# Create Json object from Circe where the value can be String or a List

Tags: scala, circe

I would like create a Json object with circe where the value can be String or a List, like:

```
val param = Map[String, Map[String, Object]](
    "param_a" -> Map[String, Object](
      "param_a1" -> "str_value",
      "param_a2" -> List(
        Map[String, String](
          "param_a2.1" -> "value_2.1",
          "param_a2.2" -> "value_2.2")
      )
    ),
```

However, then If I do

```
    param.asJson
```

It failed with

```
    Error:(61, 23) could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Map[String,Object]]]
  .postData(param.asJson.toString().getBytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide an implicit instance of `Encoder` in scope for `Object`. Try with this:

```
implicit val objEncoder: Encoder[Object] = Encoder.instance {
  case x: String => x.asJson
  case xs: List[Map[String, String]] => xs.asJson
}
```

However I would avoid using `Object` and instead provide an ADT to wrap the two possible cases, that is `String` and `List[Map[String, String]]`, but that's up to you. Furthermore, in the Scala world, `Object` is more widely known as `AnyRef` so if you just want to use `Object` I suggest you call it `AnyRef`.

P.S.: If you're using a Scala version >= 2.12.0 you can avoid typing `Encoder.instance` thanks to [SAM conversion in overloading resolution](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-in-overloading-resolution). So the code would become:

```
implicit val objEncoder: Encoder[Object] = {
  case x: String => x.asJson
  case xs: List[Map[String, String]] => xs.asJson
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a new user of this API and get few simple question

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a Quick fix is use Map[String, Json]

```
val param = Map[String, Map[String, Json]](
"param_a" -> Map[String, Json](
  "param_a1" -> "str_value".asJson,
  "param_a2" -> List(
    Map[String, String](
      "param_a2.1" -> "value_2.1",
      "param_a2.2" -> "value_2.2")
  ).asJson
),
```

Comment: This helped me figure out how to do JSON "manual" with circe.

Comment: nice to hear that